# How to backup my plugin database

Tags: backup

I want to know if is there any way to back up my plugin database, anything that the plugin is created inside the database such as tables and rows. I want to back it up and restore it to another site database. is there a plugin that could make that?

Comment: Most plugins store data in the main WordPress database, so if you back that up you'll have everything. Do you really have a plugin with a completely separate database? Which plugin?

Comment: Probably the easiest thing to do is to find the connection details the plugin is using (in wp-config? in the main WordPress database somewhere?) and use normal database backup tools to make the backup.

Comment: the plugin is Tutor LMS

Comment: Tutor LMS creates [nine extra tables in your WordPress database](https://github.com/themeum/tutor/blob/v2.1.6/classes/Tutor.php#L435-L449), but it doesn't use a separate database. A regular mysqldump backup of your WordPress database will include all of the Tutor LMS data fine.